# ckeditor paste event object not containing pasted data

Tags: ckeditor, paste

The ckeditor paste event object does not contain the properties that it should according to the API documentation:

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-paste

I am fetching the paste event as follows:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev) {
    alert('Pasted: ' + JSON.stringify(evt));
});
```

And the alert returns the following stringified object:

```
{"name":"paste","sender":{"$":{"form_select_standardlanguage": 
{"0":{},"1":{"0":{},"1":{},"2":{},"3":{},"4":{},"5":{},"6":{}},"2":
{"0":{},"1":{}}},"location":{"href":"http://somehost.com
/somefile.php","origin":"http: 
//somehost.com","protocol":"http:","host":"somehost.com", 
"hostname":"somehost.com","port":"","pathname":   
"/somefile.php","search":"?searchkey=somekey","hash":""},
"data-cke-expando":102}},"data":{"$":{"isTrusted":true}}}
```

What I need is the pasted text to check it and make changes to it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not handling the `paste` event.

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(evt) {
    evt.editor.on('paste', function (evt) {
        alert('Pasted: ' + JSON.stringify(evt));
    });
});
```